# How do I hide certain files from the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

In **Visual Studio Code**, what setting can be configured, using file patterns, to hide files from view in the sidebar's file-explorer?

I would like to hide certain groups of files, like `.meta` and `.git` files.

Comment: It's not exactly what you need, but you can at least exclude certain folders from searches by adding a "search.excludeFolders" property to your workspace settings. This was enough for me since I usually reach files by the `Ctrl-E` menu.

Comment: Nice tip. I also get to files that way and `command+p` (coming from a sublime background)

Comment: Related issue about auto-hiding .gitignored files in the side bar: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38878

Comment: I had to use **/node_modules to make it work. Just node_modules alone was not good.

Comment: @JohanWalles It seems have no result.

Comment: [shortccut comment] . . . [jD3V answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140112/how-do-i-hide-certain-files-from-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code/71776204#71776204) has this great info, change VS code settings to use .gitignore: ***`explorer.excludeGitIgnore`***

Answer (score 1675, accepted):

You can configure patterns to hide files and folders from the explorer and searches.

1. Open VS User Settings (Main menu: `File > Preferences > Settings`). This will open the setting screen.
2. Search for `files:exclude` in the search at the top.
3. Configure the User Setting with new glob patterns as needed. In this case add this pattern `node_modules/` then click OK. *The pattern syntax is powerful. You can find pattern matching details under the [Search Across Files topic](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files).*

When you are done it should look something like this:
[image]

If you want to directly edit the settings file:
For example to hide a top level node_modules folder in your workspace:

```json
"files.exclude": {
    "node_modules/": true
}
```

To hide all files that start with `._` such as `._.DS_Store` files found on OSX:

```json
"files.exclude": {
    "**/._*": true
}
```

You also have the ability to change Workspace Settings (Main menu: `File > Preferences > Workspace Settings`). Workspace settings will create a `.vscode/settings.json` file in your current workspace and will only be applied to that workspace. User Settings will be applied globally to any instance of VS Code you open, but they won't override Workspace Settings if present. Read more on customizing [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace).

Comment: Any way to exclude sym links / aliases?

Comment: To hide all node_modules in sub folders you could use: ```"**/node_modules/**": true```

Comment: In the later VSCode versions (Nov 2017) you use File>Preferences>Settings and use the dropdown on top right to select UserSettings or Workspace. Selecting Workspace will then create the .vscode folder and settings.json in your project

Comment: @becko, yes, you do have to restart your editor after changing.

Comment: This answer would be more complete if it mentioned a way to do per project, vs globally per machine.

Comment: You no longer have to restart VS Code for this to take effect.

Comment: Anyone know why this isn't working? I am trying to hide .exe files in a directory of my workspace but it isn't working. Here is an image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kz-6OZXYO1R6Ad903BPyARLlA3EOMpUQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Anguna Try `**/*.exe`.

Comment: I wanted to ignore `.pyc` files and had to add `**/*.pyc` as pattern.

Comment: `node_modules/` didnt work for me, this works : `**/node_modules`.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude all **but** certain files? Like gitignores work or something like that. And no, I do **not** want to hide all file that I have in `.gitignore` grayed out is fine but for one folder I want to manually define what to show.

Comment: After compiling any cpp file first time in vscode, it generates another file with the same name  but with no extension. I run many cpp files and after running them I always see many duplicate files with no extension. How to hide these files with no extension?

Answer (score 300):

Sometimes you just want to hide certain file types for a specific project. In that case, you can create a folder in your project folder called `.vscode` and create the `settings.json` file in there, (i.e. `.vscode/settings.json`). All settings within that file will affect your current workspace only.

For example, in a TypeScript project, this is what I have used:

```
// Workspace settings
{
    // The following will hide the js and map files in the editor
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js": true,
        "**/*.map": true
    }
}
```

Comment: VS Code now has a tab when you go to Preferences > Settings where you can switch between User Settings and Workspace Settings, so you don't have to manually create the file yourself anymore.  Great example on excluding file types--thanks!

Comment: @AliMertCakar yes you can :) just add .vscode to the list

Comment: Thanks :) Additional info: you need to restart visual studio code to hide .vscode folder

Comment: Do not mix project and workspace, they are different. Workspace has one to several projects and a project belongs to one workspace. So your settings file will affect one project.

Answer (score 50):

The "[Make Hidden](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=devine-davies.make-hidden#review-details)" extension works great!

> Make Hidden provides more control over your project's directory by enabling context menus that allow you to perform hide/show actions effortlessly, a view pane explorer to see hidden items and the ability to save workspaces to quickly toggle between bulk hidden items.

Comment: Thanks! In my opinion, this is much preferred to manually changing this setting.

Comment: Imho, this is the best answer if you are looking to **just** hide files/folders in the directory tree without side affects such as affecting search or go to file

Comment: Sadly it no longer works. I suspect it's more a problem with vscode's instability than the extension developer.

Answer (score 49):

The `__pycache__` folder and `*.pyc` files are totally unnecessary to the developer. To hide these files from the explorer view, we need to edit the settings.json for VSCode. Add the folder and the files as shown below:

```
"files.exclude": {
  ...
  ...
  "**/*.pyc": {"when": "$(basename).py"}, 
  "**/__pycache__": true,
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Where is this `when` syntax documented?

Comment: @redanimalwar
 https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts

Comment: From VSCode Intelisense: "Files with Siblings by Name: Additional check on the siblings of a matching file. Use $(basename) as variable for the matching file name." `{ "when": "$(basename).extension" }`

Answer (score 27):

I would also like to recommend vscode extension [Peep](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nwallace.peep#review-details), which allows you to toggle hide on the excluded files in your projects settings.json.

Hit <kbd>F1</kbd> for vscode command line (command palette), then

```
ext install [enter] peep [enter]
```

You can bind "extension.peepToggle" to a key like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (same as <kbd>F1</kbd> by default) for easy toggling. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for key bindings, enter `peep`, select Peep Toggle and add your binding.

Answer (score 24):

For `.meta` files while using Unity3D, I found the best pattern for hiding is:

```json
"files.exclude": {
  "*/**/**.meta": true
}
```

This captures all folders and subfolders, and will pick up `foo.cs.meta` in addition to `foo.meta`

Comment: Worked for `.pyc` files generated by *python*.

Comment: It works, but then the global search stops working with error: ```Error parsing glob ... invalid use of **; must be one path component```, should be ```"*/**/*.meta": true```

Comment: Your glob is unnecessarily long, it can be simplified to `"**/*.meta"`

Answer (score 21):

### 2022 New File-explorer Features

###### *There are a couple very cool new features that let devs configure the files that show in the sidebar, as well as offering new ways of hiding files, while keeping them accessible.*

##### This answer covers

1. **`"explorer.fileNesting"`** (NEW *as of April-2022*)
2. **`"files.exclude"`**
3. **`explorer.excludeGitIgnore`** (new as of June-2022)

#### File Excludes

So the best answer included in this post, originally, was the `"files.exclude"`

---

### VS Code's File Nesting Feature

Because **"File Nesting"** is ***IMO*** one of the coolest features added to VS Code in recent releases, I thought I'd take the time to create a *animated GIF-image* that shows how it works in real-time.

###### *Below is a `.gif` image that shows the `explorer.fileNesting` feature being used in Real-time*

[image: Hiding Files in VS Code File-nesting Feature "explorer.fileNesting"]

File nesting is very cool, it is important to note, like most VS Code features, it does need to be custom configured for your personal development environment.

- Personally I find this is a good addition for the workspace scoped *`settings.json`* configuration file. Unless you only ever use VS Code for developing the same type of projects, using the same project template, over & over again (which I understand some people do) I suggest using it to configure each individual project.
- An alternative is per-language configuration. I don't use it this way, but it is very helpful with TypeScript's tsc emissions. ***For Example*** ***`.d.ts`*** files & ***`*map`*** files, they can configured to always be nested into `*.js` files, with the same name. Or the `*.js` files can be configured to nest under the `*.ts` files.

The above two notes point out that this is a feature aimed at improving the environment for compiled languages that have a compiler that emits project-build files; and specifically **"transpilers"** like **TypeScript**  in other words,

###### Below shows a "File Nesting" configuration that you'll likely find written to *`"./.vscode/settings.json"`* file that belongs to a TypeScript project.

```
    "explorer.fileNesting.patterns": {
          "*.ts": "${capture}.js",
          "*.js": "${capture}.js.map, ${capture}.min.js, ${capture}.d.ts",
          "*.mts": "${capture}.mjs, ${capture}.d.mts",
          "*.mjs": "${capture}.mjs.map, ${capture}.min.mjs, ${capture}.d.mts",
          "*.cts": "${capture}.js",
          "*.cjs": "${capture}.js.map, ${capture}.min.js, ${capture}.d.ts",
          "*.jsx": "${capture}.js",
          "*.tsx": "${capture}.ts",
    }
```

The above configuration is actually from one of my projects, and it results in the following behavior:

[image]

I have included below, a complete list of All available configurations, as well as the link to the official release-notes *(early form of documentation)* that covers the ***"VS Code File-nesting Feature"***.

###### *As of* `2022-06-17` *the following list contains all configurations available for "VS Code's File Nesting Feature".*

1. ***`explorer.fileNesting.enabled`***

   - Controls whether file nesting is enabled at-large. It can be set either globally or for a specific workspace.
2. ***`explorer.fileNesting.expand`***

   - Controls whether nested files are expanded by default.
3. ***`explorer.fileNesting.patterns`***

   - Controls how files are nested. The default configuration provides nesting intelligence for TypeScript and JavaScript projects, but you're encouraged to modify this to fit your own project's structure. Some examples:

- ###### [VS CODE'S OFFICIAL RELEASE NOTES ON THE NEW FILE NESTING FEATURE](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_explorer-file-nesting)

---

#### File Excludes

---

> ###### NOTE: *"File excludes, has been covered by other answers so I will be brief."*
>
> ###### *"It's important we cover `files.exclude` though, as the next feature builds on it."*

***File-nesting is awesome, but don't exclude `files.exclude` Just yet***. Comparing features like `explorer.fileNesting`, and `files.exclude` against each-other is not very helpful. It is actually best to look at the new "File Nesting" feature as either an alternative to files.exclude, or as a complementing feature to `files.exclude`. There's no need to go indepth about using `explorer.fileNesting` as an alternative, so lets talk a bit about it complimenting `files.exclude`.

There are several ways you can use the two settings to configure your projects **"file-explorer"** *(the file-tree in the side-bar)*. I use both explorer.fileNesting & `"files.exclude"`. I nest certain groups of files that obviously share somthing in common. A common example given in the official docs for the file nesting feature is using file nesting to hide your `package-lock.json` file under your `package.json` file, which is obviously a great way to make use of file nesting.

However I take it a step further: I also hide my .npmrc file, and if I am writing an NPM-Package, I hide my .npmignore file with the package files too.

###### Here are two groups I create

- `package.json`

  - `package-lock.json`
  - `.npmignore`
  - `.npmrc`
- `eslintrc.json`

  - `.eslintignore`
  - `.prettierrc`
  - `.markdownlintrc`

The problem is with file nesting, you get a bunch of 1-offs, like .editorconfig (ya I can place it with my `.eslintrc.json` group, but it doesn't really fit their. And what about .gitignore. I suppose I could just leave `.gitignore` in the view.

**Or I could use `files.exclude`**, and configure my `"files.exclude": {}` object in my project's `.vscode/settings.json` file to hide files like `.gitignore`, `LICENSE`, `.editorconfig`, etc...

I can also use it to hide directorys **this is somthing File Nesting cannot do**. I use it to hide my "build" dir & "node_modules" dir.

By default, `files.exclude` hides project's `.git/` directory, which is why you never see it.

Below is the default configuration I use for ESM NodeJS TypeScript projects, which is what most of my projects are. The configuration is generic, and changes from project to project.

```
  "files.exclude": {
    // -------- PROJECT DIRECTORIES --------
    "**/.git/": true,
    "node_modules/": true,
    "out/": true,
    "typings/": true,

    // ------- PROJECT FILES -------
    "LICENSE": true,
    "README.md": true
  },

  "explorer.fileNesting.patterns": {
    "*.ts": "${capture}.js",
    "*.js": "${capture}.js.map, ${capture}.min.js, ${capture}.d.ts",
    "*.jsx": "${capture}.js",
    "*.tsx": "${capture}.ts",
    ".eslintrc.*": ".eslintignore, .editorconfig, .prettierrc",
    "tsconfig.json": "tsconfig.*.json, package.json, .gitignore",
  },
```

##### The Latest Feature of the Bunch, Which I Edited in a bit after editing in File Nesting's new settings, is the new...

#### GitIgnore Exclude Feature

This feature allows you to configure ***VS Code*** to treat entries in your `.gitignore` file, as if they were included in your `files.exclude` object. The means that the File Explorer actually parses your .gitignore file, and reads its contents, then hides the files you configure it too.

To configure the setting to on use `explorer.excludeGitIgnore`.

Remember, this setting, like the other two features, should not be thought of from a perspective of,

> "Is "GitIgnore Exclude" better than "Files Exclude"?

Its unhelpful, and counter productive to think in this way. Git Excludes (as the release notes say)...

> *...works alongside files.exclude to hide unwanted files from the Explorer.*
>        ~ ***VS Code Release Notes*** `v1.68`

- ***[You can read more about GitIgnore Excludes Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_68#_hide-files-in-explorer-based-on-gitignore)***

---

Comment: How to make it work with directories?

Comment: @Simeon Sorry I am so late getting back to you Simeon. You cannot get fileNesting to work with directories, but you can now use ***"GitIgnore Exclude"*** to help with that. Read the new answer I just posted. It includes a whole bunch about the new exclude feature released in the latest `v1.68` release of VS Code.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using VSCode:

- File > Preferences > Settings
- Search for:

`files:exclude`

- Then add

`**/node_modules`

- Click `OK`.

You shouldn't need to restart or reload VSCode to take effect

Comment: I also search for '.gitignore' in the settings and find "Explorer: Exclude GitIgnore", "Search: Use Ignore Files" and a couple more.

Answer (score 4):

If your working on a **Angular 2+** application, and like me you like a clean working environment, follow @omt66 answer and paste the below in your settings.json file.
I recommend you do this once all the initial setup has been completed.

**Note**: This will actually hide the .vscode folder (with settings.json) in as well. (Open in your native file explorer / text editor if you need to make changes afterwards)

https://pastebin.com/X2NL6Vxb

```json
{
  "files.exclude": {
      ".vscode":true,
      "node_modules/":true,
      "dist/":true,
      "e2e/":true,
      "*.json": true,
      "**/*.md": true,
      ".gitignore": true,
      "**/.gitkeep":true,
      ".editorconfig": true,
      "**/polyfills.ts": true,
      "**/main.ts": true,
      "**/tsconfig.app.json": true,
      "**/tsconfig.spec.json": true,
      "**/tslint.json": true,
      "**/karma.conf.js": true,
      "**/favicon.ico": true,
      "**/browserslist": true,
      "**/test.ts": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To hide certain files from VSCode Explorer, go to the following steps.

1. Go to settings
2. Type **Exclude files**
3. Add **/*.meta and save it.

Answer (score 3):

To hide **pycache** add `**/__pycache__` to the `Exclude` section in settings:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is perfect if you're looking to **hide** something like `node_modules`.
In the case you're working with a static meta-framework like Astro.js, you'll end up with `index.astro` files but also get a lot of noise because of `dist/test/index.html` or `/dist/about-page/index.html` etc... pages.

To exclude them from the command palette **search** but still be able to inspect the `dist` folder in your files tree, I recommend using the following in a `.vscode/settings.json` file

```json
{
  "search.exclude": {
    "dist/**": true
  }
}
```

That way, you still keep it visible while not having it polluting your `ctrl + p` search.

---

PS: more info can be [found here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#:%7E:text=files.exclude%60%20setting.-,%22search.exclude%22%3A%20%7B,-%22) (submit the URL again after opening it to go to the highlight directly).

Comment: IDK, if this is of help to you, but your answer caused this question to pop up at the top of my feed, and I wanted to include a new feature that VSCode released with this question. U can see it below.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the past as I was looking to remove the .class files generated after we suceessfully run .java files so .class files are created automatically after compilation and .exe files are created after compiling C or C++ code.

The most simple method to do this is to change your workspace settings by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> and selecting `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings` from the popup. After that scroll to the `Files: Exclude` row and add a tag - `**/*.class` in the list and now the .class files will not be shown in the Vscode Project File Explorer.

You can do the same method to remove .exe files by using the tag `**/*.exe`
for C & C++ files.

Thanks

Manpreet Singh

Answer (score -1):

Open Settings and search for  `Files.Exclude`  then click on  `add pattern`   then it will give a notification
`Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.`
Now open that  `settings.json`  file and search for files.exclude{ } block and include
`"**/*.exe": true`   Here I use .exe as example, Instead of that use the extension whatever you want to block.
I hope this helps.