# How to filter files shown in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How would you filter the files shown in the folder view in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)?

Reference: [Filter files shown in folder](https://web.archive.org/web/20151222061300/https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7755693-filter-files-shown-in-folder-view)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide .js.map files in Visual Studio Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587949/hide-js-map-files-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Your reference no longer points to anything useful

Comment: This has a GUI now! [See my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55556206/1494454)

Comment: I was looking for something like Xcode's filter feature in the file navigator. Is this not possible in VSCode ?

Comment: This question was confusing for me. I expected to see a reference to how to enable a search box or something to filter files displayed in the explorer, as I type :)

Answer (score 101):

**Hiding files and folders**

The **files.exclude** setting lets you define patterns to hide files and folders from several places in VS Code like the explorer and search. Once defined, files and folders matching any of the patterns will be hidden.

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js": true
    }
}
```

**Hide derived resources**

If you use a language that compiles to another file at the same location of the source file, like TypeScript does to JavaScript, you can easily set an expression to hide those derived files:

```
"**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"}
```

Such a pattern will match on any JavaScript file (**/*.js), but only if a sibling file with the same name and extension, *.ts in this example, is present. The same technique can be used for other transpiled languages, like Coffee Script or Less/Sass, too.

Source: [VS Code v0.5.0 (July 2015)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v0_5_0)

Comment: In case anyone coming across this is as confused as I was, this is a Visual Studio Code user setting, not a project setting.

Comment: "when" is really usefull - unfortunately it doesn't work for my map files like  "**/*.js.map": { "when": "$(basename).ts"}

Comment: @Gerfried, FWIW, if you use `{"when": "$(basename)"}`, then your `.js.map` will not show.
(notice I did not set an extension...)

Comment: @EricLiprandi Why is that? I don't see any explanation of what exactly `basename` does, and the `$(basename)` gives the impression it's the command, but clearly it's not.

Comment: @pborenstein, I don't know where this is documented. I just tried. The logic is that `$(basename)` is the name of the file without the extension. The extension of `file.js.map` is `.map`, so its basename is `file.js`.

Comment: Although `*/.js.map": {"when":"$(basename).ts"}` won't work since the basename is file.js, this will hide the maps since each map has a corresponding sibling js file:

`*/.js.map": {"when":"$(basename).js"}`

Comment: Simply adding `"**/*.map": true ` in the user settings will hide all map files. Here's my files.exclude setting to exclude javascript and map files for a given TypeScript file
`"files.exclude": {
    "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"},
    "**/*.map": { "when": "$(basename)"}
  }`

Comment: What would be the pattern to hide **all** subfolders?

Comment: To **restore the excluded files**, there is an extension : Toggle Excluded Files - Visual Studio Marketplace https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amodio.toggle-excluded-files

Answer (score 66):

In version after VScode 1.70 (July 2022) all you need to do is

1. Click on explorer pane to get it in focus
2. Press Ctrl+F or F3 to search.
3. Type the text you want to search

Comment: how do i filter by ending? i only want to see .tex files, but the directory also contains files ending in .synctex.gz. these are matched by .tex because the letters matched don't even have to be consecutive in the filename. how can I refine that?

Comment: @user313032, I don't think there is any way to avoid this.  It just matches characters even if they are apart. Here is official documentation.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_explorer

Comment: I like VS Code. But this is the most badly designed feature I've used in it. e.g. 1. typing with the Explorer view highlighted - who thought this was a good idea?! 2. I can filter by directory name but then can't see any of the files in that directory making the feature pretty useless.

Comment: @Snowcrash, you could just use filter mode to narrow the files shown and then click on what you want and switch back to highlight mode or just remove the filter.  

It would be more intuitive to have input fix for search but that would take some space.

Comment: if you use vscode >= v1.7 (after July 2022) Please check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73039128/10655742 -> Use `F3` or `Ctrl + F`

Comment: That change drove me crazy! I thought that feature got removed!

Comment: @yacaFx, me too. I think new way is more intuitive.

Comment: This only works for files you can see. My **workaround**, I search a regex matching the beginning of a file. Ex: I want to see all readme files from my projects:

CTRL + SHIFT + F => ALT + R => paste regex `^(?<!\n)` => files to include `README.MD`

Answer (score 27):

If you only want to change the setting for this project, then do the following:

File > Save Workspace As > ... enter your {project name}

Then open file: `{project name}.code-workspace`
And update section `settings`.

Sample:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "files.exclude": {
            "**/*.log": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: with this solution, does it mean when open a folder for editing (i.e., project) that I would need to manually perform a "Open Workspace" action then select the `{project name}.code-workspace` file?

Comment: @lordhog, only if the file hasn't been created yet

Comment: can the @settings section be at the level of each individual folder?

Comment: @AlexGordon, in case, you're opening that folder from VSCode, otherwise would be ignored.

Answer (score 18):

[VScode 1.70 (July 2022)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_tree-find-control) should improve on this "tree filter" feature.
(Available today in [Code insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/))

See [issue 70646](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70646) and [PR 152481](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/152481):

> ### Support find widget in lists/trees
>
> This PR replaces the existing list/tree type filter:
>
> [image: old]
>
> with an *bona fide* `find` widget:
>
> [image: new -- https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22350/179354305-66d6a9cf-c74d-4f79-903e-ee501a6f41fc.png]

> While a seemingly simple change, this has some (desired) consequences when searching/filtering in trees. Namely:
>
> - We will restore simple keyboard navigation by default.
>   That is: pressing the letter <kbd>A</kbd> will focus the next element which starts with `A`.
> - Initiating a search operation requires pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>, like the editor.
> - While searching, focus is in the find input box as opposed to the list itself.
>   Pressing <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> will focus the first list element which was found.
> - We'll preserve all custom behavior of context keys, eg. used by the VIM extension).
>   In VIM, the pre-existing / command will trigger simple keyboard navigation, as opposed to opening the find widget.
>   The VIM extension has the option to change this behavior themselves.

And:

> In general:
>
> - `Keyboard navigation` is now called `type navigation`
> - `Filter on type` is now called `find mode`, aligned with a new `find` concept
>
> #### Settings
>
> - `workbench.list.keyboardNavigation` has been renamed to `workbench.list.defaultFindMode`
> - `workbench.list.automaticKeyboardNavigation` has been deleted
>
> #### Commands
>
> - `list.toggleKeyboardNavigation` has been renamed to `list.triggerTypeNavigation`
> - `list.find` has been added
> - `list.closeFind` has been added
> - `list.toggleFilterOnType` has been renamed to `list.toggleFindMode`
>
> #### Context Keys
>
> Mainly used by the vim extension:
>
> - `listSupportsKeyboardNavigation` has been renamed to `listSupportsTypeNavigation`
> - `listAutomaticKeyboardNavigation` has been renamed to `listTypeNavigationMode`

Comment: I was excited, but then I realized it will only filter down to files I have in view in expanded folders.  If the folders are collapsed it doesn't show those files.... Sad....

Comment: @RyanMann True, there are still improvements left to be implemented for this feature.

Comment: The hint `Initiating a search operation requires pressing Ctrl-F or F3, like the editor.` made my day - I was just navigating but not filtering just by typing. MANY THANKS

Comment: It's what i was looking for in recent update of vscode

Comment: doc ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_tree-find-control

Comment: @MohamedAllal Thank you. I have edited the answer to include your link.

Answer (score 11):

"With the focus on the File Explorer start to type part of the file name you want to match.You will see a filter box in the top-right of the File Explorer showing what you have typed so far and matching file names will be highlighted."

"Hovering over the filter box and selecting Enable Filter on Type will show only matching files/folders."

documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_filtering-the-document-tree

Comment: This looks like it could be great, but if folders aren't expanded, then they aren't included when I tested this.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer your question as it is stated, because there just isn't a way to do that afaik.

However, if you want to locate a particular file within the opened folder, given a partial name or its extension: the best way to do that is to use `Ctrl+P` and start typing.

Example: note it is showing .xml files with the string faction in its name
[image]

I have tried several times to make use of the explorer panel, and always come to the conclusion id rather use windows explorer (which you can quickly get to by via right click and open folder on an open document tab).