# How to exclude folder from "Explore" tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to exclude several folders on the `Explore` tab in Visual Studio Code. To do that, I have added a following `jsconfig.json` to the root of my project:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

But the `node_modules` folder is still visible in the directory tree.

What am I doing wrong? Are there any other options?

Comment: It seems most answers are suggesting to change this configuration in _Workspace Settings_. However, I don't need `node_modules` to show up on _any_ project. So I would set it globally in **User Settings** instead.

Answer (score 711, accepted):

Use [files.exclude](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace):

- Go to **File -> Preferences -> Settings** (or on Mac **Code -> Preferences -> Settings**)
- Pick the `workspace settings` tab
- Add this code to the `settings.json` file displayed on the right side:

```json
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.

{
    "settings": {
        "files.exclude": {
            "**/.git": true,         // this is a default value
            "**/.DS_Store": true,    // this is a default value

            "**/node_modules": true, // this excludes all folders 
                                    // named "node_modules" from 
                                    // the explore tree

            // alternative version
            "node_modules": true    // this excludes the folder 
                                    // only from the root of
                                    // your workspace 
        }
    }
}
```

If you chose **File -> Preferences -> User Settings** then you configure the exclude folders globally for your current user.

Comment: Just if somebody wonders: A trailing slash isn't helping (nor harming) in limiting the exclude to Folders only. i.e. `"**/BACKUP/": true` is just as good/bad as without the last slash.

Comment: The value you provide on the RHS appears to be merged with the value on the LHS. Presumably one would have to copy the value from the LHS and set it to `false` to overwrite the default values.

Comment: Correction: It should be "**/node_modules": true

Comment: How does inheritance work here? Do I have to list *all* excludes or just the ones not listed in user settings?

Comment: The second comment is more useful than the accepted answer. It introduces `search.exclude`. which actually allows you to see files with vital info such as packages and versions, but stops useless search results.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the current version of Code (1.28.2), the `files.exclude` key belongs **inside** the `settings` key of the `code-workspace` file.

Comment: What would be the patter to exclude all subfolders?

Comment: I want to exclude all files/folders from `.gitignore`. What to do?

Comment: .. with current VS Code versions, using CTRL+SHIFT+P and then entering `Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings` will get you to the text version of `settings.json` view directly (otherwise, settings is shown as interface fields by default)

Comment: how can we check in these settings per project, without checking in the .vscode folder (whihc does not seem to be a good idea)?

Comment: As of version 1.44.2 this doesn't seem to work anymore. The second answer has the correct syntax. Full syntax of settings.json with default values can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings

Comment: Has anyone succeeded to make the root only version (ie "node_modules": true) work?

Comment: the outmost brackets should not be there

Comment: files.exclude didn't work inside a settings object for me. Instead, using files.exclude at the top level worked.

Answer (score 147):

### GUI way

1. Go to "File -> Preferences -> Settings" (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>) then:
   [image: exclude tutorial via screenshot]
2. Type "exclude" to the search bar.
3. Select the "Workspace" tab if you want this change to only effect your current project instead of each one.
4. Click the "Add Pattern" button.

### Code way

1. To open the [`settings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) file:

   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Mac, then type "Open Workspace Settings (JSON)".
   - OR, on older versions you can click the little `{}` icon at the top right corner of the GUI tab:
     [image: Click brackets icon to open settings.json]
2. Add excluded folders to `files.exclude`. Also check out `search.exclude` and `files.watcherExclude` as they might be useful too. This snippet contains their explanations and defaults:

   ```js
    {
      // Configure glob patterns for excluding files and folders. 
      // For example, the files explorer decides which files and folders to show 
      // or hide based on this setting. 
      // Read more about glob patterns [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options).
      "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.svn": true,
        "**/.hg": true,
        "**/CVS": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true
      },
      // Configure glob patterns for excluding files and folders in searches. 
      // Inherits all glob patterns from the `files.exclude` setting.   
      // Read more about glob patterns [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options).
      "search.exclude": {
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/bower_components": true
      },
      // Configure glob patterns of file paths to exclude from file watching. 
      // Patterns must match on absolute paths 
      // (i.e. prefix with ** or the full path to match properly). 
      // Changing this setting requires a restart. 
      // When you experience Code consuming lots of cpu time on startup, 
      // you can exclude large folders to reduce the initial load.
      "files.watcherExclude": {
        "**/.git/objects/**": true,
        "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
        "**/node_modules/*/**": true
      }
    }
   ```

For more details on the other settings, see the [official `settings.json` reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

Comment: omg, `watcherExclude` may be just what I need to deal with major lag due to watching bazel autogenerated files... thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 120):

In newer versions of VS Code, you navigate to settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>), and make sure to select *Workspace Settings* at the top right.

[image]

Then add a `files.exclude` option to specify patterns to exclude.

You can also add `search.exclude` if you only want to exclude a file from search results, and not from the folder explorer.

Comment: Exclude from search while still being able to browse files in the explorer - exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for specifying `Workspace Settings`

Comment: I had to place `files.exclude` inside `settings:{ ... }` when applying it to the *workspace settings* ([.code-workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) file) otherwise it complained on the lines of the property being unknown. There was a _third_ "Folder settings" tab (.vscode/settings.json) in which it worked in the outermost braces.

Comment: Here is an extension if you want to easily [toggle the excluded files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amodio.toggle-excluded-files)

Answer (score 18):

In version 1.28 of Visual Studio Code `"files.exclude"` must be placed within a `settings` node.

Resulting in a workspace file that looks like:

```json
{
    "settings": {
        "files.exclude": {
            "**/node_modules": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's this ***Explorer Exclude*** extension that exactly does this. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RedVanWorkshop.explorer-exclude-vscode-extension

It adds an option to hide current folder/file to the right click menu.
It also adds a vertical tab ***Hidden Items*** to explorer menu where you can see currently hidden files & folders and can toggle them easily.

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of VSCode this moved to a folder-specific configuration block.

- Go to `File` -> `Preferences` -> `Settings` (or on Mac `Code` -> `Preferences` -> `Settings`)
- Pick the  *Folder Settings* tab

Then add a "files.exclude" block, listing the directory globs you would like to exclude:

```json
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/bin": true,
        "**/obj": true
    },
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer using Visual Studio Code on Mac in 2021. I am using Code v1.60.

1. Open Settings (command-P).
2. Select the Workspace Tab.

[image]

3. Use the Settings search bar to search for "exclude". Then look for the section that says "Files: Exclude". Click on the blue button that says "Add Pattern".

[image]

4. A new text field will appear. Add the name of the directory that you want excluded. If the directory is named `excluded_directory`, then type in `**/excluded_directory`. Click on OK.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To avoid duplicities you can just use the `.gitignore` file and use property in `settings.json`:

```json
"explorer.excludeGitIgnore":true
```

You can find it in **Settings**, I recommend using the settings only for the **Workspace**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can configure patterns to hide files and folders from the explorer and searches.

1. Open VS User Settings (Main menu: File > Preferences > Settings). This will open the setting screen.
2. Search for `files:exclude` in the search at the top.
3. Configure the User Setting with new glob patterns as needed. In this case, add this pattern node_modules/ then click OK. The pattern syntax is powerful. You can find pattern matching details under the Search Across Files topic.

```json
    {
       "files.exclude": {
        ".vscode":true,
        "node_modules/":true,
        "dist/":true,
        "e2e/":true,
        "*.json": true,
        "**/*.md": true,
        ".gitignore": true,
        "**/.gitkeep":true,
        ".editorconfig": true,
        "**/polyfills.ts": true,
        "**/main.ts": true,
        "**/tsconfig.app.json": true,
        "**/tsconfig.spec.json": true,
        "**/tslint.json": true,
        "**/karma.conf.js": true,
        "**/favicon.ico": true,
        "**/browserslist": true,
        "**/test.ts": true,
        "**/*.pyc": true,
        "**/__pycache__/": true
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If those files are defined at `.gitignore` you can exclude them by:

- **File** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings** (or on Mac Code -> Preferences -> Settings)
- **Features** -> **Search** -> check **Use Ignore files**

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the extension that named `Hide Files`

Url: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=roonie007.hide-files

[image: Easy to hide files and folders]

Answer (score -15):

I managed to remove the errors by disabling the validations:

```
{
    "javascript.validate.enable": false,
    "html.validate.styles": false,
    "html.validate.scripts": false,
    "css.validate": false,
    "scss.validate": false
}
```

Obs: My project is a PWA using StyledComponents, React, Flow, Eslint and Prettier.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question at all.