# Visual Studio Code: make exception to files.exclude?

Tags: visual-studio-code, node-modules

So in Visual Studio Code, I have a `.vscode/settings.json` which defines some directories to not show.

I have some `node_modules` that are specific to my project and maintained inside my repo. They all start with `mycompany`. I'd like to show those in VSCode, but not others.

Here's what I have so far in `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    // From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258543/how-can-i-exclude-a-directory-from-visual-studio-code-explore-tab
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,        
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/.vscode": true,
        "**/.sass-cache": true,
        "node_modules/mycompany**": false, // Hoping this will override next line
        "node_modules/**": true
    }
}
```

I've tried swapping the order of the last two lines but that doesn't work either. **How can I ignore all files in a directory unless they start with a particular set of characters?**

Comment: I am looking for the same thing, but according to VSCode github issue, it is not support yet. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/869

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to do the same thing, and also couldn't find a way to achieve this via `files.exclude` setting, however I found a workaround utilizes another setting - `"explorer.excludeGitIgnore": true`.

Enabled this setting, added `.gitignore` that expresses what I need, which in your case would be:

```
# .gitignore
node_modules/**
!node_modules/mycompany**
```

Note: this works even though I am not using git in this repo, I basically have a `.gitignore` that is not in any git repo.

Answer (score 5):

Found a solution, not very elegant though )

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/node_modules/[^m]*": true,
        "**/node_modules/?[^y]*": true,
        "**/node_modules/??[^c]*": true,
        "**/node_modules/???[^o]*": true,
        "**/node_modules/????[^m]*": true,
        "**/node_modules/?????[^p]*": true,
        "**/node_modules/??????[^a]*": true,
        "**/node_modules/???????[^n]*": true,
        "**/node_modules/????????[^y]*": true
    }
}
```

Comment: This will ignore everything except stuff that **starts** with `mycompany`. In order to also exclude e.g. `mycompanyxyz`, you'd have to add `"**/node_modules/mycompany?*": true`