# Visual studio is too slow with Angular2 because of node_modules

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, node-modules

I have an asp.net project with Angular4 as front-end.

I have created my Angular project by angular-cli and then added this angular project to the main project and included in the solution explorer.

After adding that project, the speed of the visual studio got extremely slow when I was trying to do something on the solution explorer. I thought it must be because of the *node_modules* directory, as it has many folders inside so I excluded it from the project. I think that was correct and I solved the issue but still I am running into another issue. The solution explorer now is slow when adding something to the project. I guess it must be again related to the *node_modules* directory. I am just wondering if we can tell Visual Studio not to traverse the *node_modules* directory  when it is traversing something.

Using Visual Studio 2017 update 3 (15.3.5) Community Edition. Not using other extensions like Resharper.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2017 Community. But I don't use Resharper.

Comment: Updated the main question, which is what you should do when answering these kinds of queries. You can now also delete these additional comments.  That way people reading the question don't have to plough through all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude **node_modules** folder from indexing

Go to **File -> Preferences -> Settings** (or on Mac Code -> Preferences -> Settings)

Edit **settings.json**

Duplicate : [How can I exclude a directory from Visual Studio Code "Explore" tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258543/how-can-i-exclude-a-directory-from-visual-studio-code-explore-tab)

Comment: The question isn't about Visual Studio Code, It's **about Visual Studio**.