# Folder "libs" (with "s") is not displayed in the treeview

Tags: visual-studio-code

Probably due to a setting (which one?) : my "libs" folder isn't displayed in VS Code.

Renaming the folder like "lib" (so without the "s" or everything else is ok).

[image: libs isn't displayed]

I've already reload the editor with extensions disabled and it doesn't help.

Can you please help me: which setting should I update to get my /public/lib folder ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a setting "files.exclude" that could be the reason:

- Press F1
- Type settings
- Select "Open Workspace Settings"

Check settings on the right side. If "files.exclude" contains your "libs" folder, remove it.

See also:

- [How can I exclude a directory from Visual Studio Code "Explore" tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258543/how-can-i-exclude-a-directory-from-visual-studio-code-explore-tab)
- http://donovanbrown.com/post/Hide-folders-in-Visual-Studio-Code-Explorer