# NodeJs copy packages to docker image

Tags: docker, npm

I have followed file structure

```
...
   - public
   - app
   - docker/
        - node-js/Dockerfile
   docker-compose.yml
   package.json
```

in my dockerfile I have a logic to copy `package.json` and run `npm install`

```
FROM node:12.0.0-alpine

MAINTAINER Bogdan Dubyk <bogdan.dubyk@gmail.comn>

COPY package.json /var/www/frontend/
RUN npm install

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

but I'm getting an error `ERROR: Service 'node-js' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder184577258/package.json: no such file or directory` while building the image, looks like Dockerfile looking for files only inside his own folder? is it possible to copy files from outside the folder?

I tried  `COPY ../../package.json /var/www/frontend/` but also getting error `ERROR: Service 'node-js' failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../package.json ()`

Comment: CD to var/www/frontend  and then run npm install

Comment: umm, the issue is not with `run npm install`, docker can't copy `package.json`. I have tried to change `WORKDIR`, but it also not helped

Comment: its because your dockerfile directory does not have the package.json, so move your dockerfile to the root and it will work

Comment: I know it will work if I move dockerfile to same dir as `package.json`,but i do not want to move it, i have all docker related files in `docker` folder

Comment: Question  is if its possible to copy files from outside of dockerfile dir

Comment: then try with ../../package.json...

Comment: Tried and getting error, `ERROR: Service 'node-js' failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../package.json ()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258543/how-can-i-exclude-a-directory-from-visual-studio-code-explore-tab. Try this while building