# Is there a way to stop tracking folder in VS Code with out gitignore?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

I have a dist folder that I want to build locally and put it on Heroku every time during development. But I want VS Code to stop tracking files in the folder, for example during a search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33277809/13378612

You can exclude the dist folder in your workspace using [files.exclude](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace). (Of course this does not prevent git to track the changes in dist.)

Comment: I'd appreciate any comments regarding the quality of my answer in order to avoid down voting in the future.

Comment: Actually your comment was more helpful, thank you! Unfortunately I don't have rights to vote yet.

Comment: Now I can, fixed id :)

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you are mixing [git](/questions/tagged/git) with your IDE: say your project folder was not tracked via Git, then you would not have a .gitignore file to edit.

I found this [very nice guide](https://www.donovanbrown.com/post/Hide-folders-in-Visual-Studio-Code-Explorer) by Donovan Brown to achieve what you ask. I'll post the relevant steps:

1. in Preferences > Open Workspace Settings
2. search for `files.exclude` in the yaml
3. add pairs `<URL>:<bool>`, if bool is true the file is ignored