# Visual Studio Code .vscode directory disappeared from workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

Today when I opened my workspace in VS code, one of my extensions displayed an error message, telling me that there is some option missing in settings. I went looking for it in settings.json, just to find out my whole .vscode directory is gone along with settings.json file in it, and now I have to create everything from scratch once again. I checked reciclyng  bin, it wasn't there either. I don't know whether it's a VS code problem, or somme Windows 10 shenanigans, but I can't be sure this won't happen again, because I have no idea how it happened in the first place.

Comment: If you're using a version control system (like git) to manage your project source files, you may want to include the `.vscode` directory. It's also useful in a team context to synchronize settings between all members using vscode.

Comment: the ./vscode/settings.json was in gitignore file. Although I remember I used git stash -u, and then git stash pop recently, maybe it has something to do with disappearance, but as I've already said, the file was in gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on a collaborative project with colleagues or other devs then someone might have changed the settings in .vscode/setting.json

Check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44003514/12828071)

You can exclude files and folder to hide in workspace by adding `files.exlude` in the settings.json file