# How can I exclude files from "Go to File" (Quick Open) in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to exclude files from VS Code's "go to file" feature (⌘P) *while keeping* the files visible in the file explorer? I tried changing the "files.exclude" setting [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31639564/9021204), but it hides files in the file explorer in addition to excluding them from "go to file."

Answer (score 0):

This should happen once you put appropriate exclude patterns into the `search.exclude` setting. Quick Open shares the exclude patterns used by the search feature. Note that `search.exclude` inherits all glob patterns from the `files.exclude` setting.