# VS Code - Search in Source Control View

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a search feature that we can use to search the files in the Source Control View (in the Activity Bar)? Let's say we have tens of files changed and when we go to the Source Control view, how do I find and add a specific file to the Staged state by using the UI?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73039128/836330 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/73039598/836330 It works the same in a SCM view as it does in the Explorer or a TreeView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pick any of files and start to type filename you want to find. Then typed text appear in the right upper corner of SCM View and you can filter out searched files.

See how it looks:

[image]

Also this way works in the Explorer view.

Upd. Official description of feature: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_filtering-the-document-tree

Comment: @MertAkcakaya I'm also use v1.40.1 and feature is working. See more here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_filtering-the-document-tree

Comment: Oh, I see it doesn't work for me because I'm using a Vim emulator extension. Thank you!