# Is it possible to add search filter/box to a tree view component?

Tags: visual-studio-code, treeview, code-snippets

Im making an extension and I'm curious is it possible to add a search filter/box to a tree component?

Im currently coding the extension in javascript but im not sure if its possible or not

[This is what i want to add in at the top of my tree view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vchh0.png)

Comment: use a `WebViewView`, you can use any HTML/CSS/JS you want

Comment: Check [VSCode 1.70 (July 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73039128/6309) which seems to have implemented something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It will be built-in to vscode in v1.70.  Here it is working in a treeView that I wrote for vertical tabgroups:

[image: find in a tree view]

The placement of the find widget is a little unfortunate right now.

WHen you have focus in the treeView <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is bound to the command `list.find` which brings up the Find in list/treeView widget.

You need to enable the `filter` option icon to see it work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only function only searches through the `TreeViewItem.label` ignoring the description or any other additional metadata I'd like to be searching/filtering through. :/

Comment: @maninak I couldn't find an issue requesting a broader search.  It is an interesting idea though.