# How do I shut off the new Explorer Ctrl+F Find tool in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, find, ide

I realize that Microsoft had some sort of reason for adding the new "Find" tool in the folder EXPLORER section of VSC.. but... I'm a creature of habit. When I click on a file and then press Ctrl+F, I immediately start typing the value I'm looking for. The results used to look like this in the file editor pane...

[image]

But with my last update, when I click on the file in the EXPLORER and press Ctrl+F, I am now getting this NEW small tool in the EXPLORER pane, and the cursor goes THERE. I type away and nothing happens in the file editor until I swear a few near-curse-words and have to click over in the file editor and then press Ctrl+F again and start all over to type the search string. It's bugging me because its old habit.

[image]

How can I go back to the old way of how it worked? Is there a simple configuration buried somewhere I can change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't say see a setting to set the old filter-search method as the default in the Explorer.  You can disable the `list.find` command on which the new find widget in the Explorer depends in your `keybindings.json` which has the effect you want:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f",
    "command": "-list.find",
    // "when": "listFocus && listSupportsFind"
  }
```

Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> with focus in the Explorer will open the editor Find Widget with focus.

But you lose the ability to filter other lists with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, such as TreeViews (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73039598/836330 forexample).

---

The better solution, IMO, is to set up a macro which works when you have `explorerFocus` and use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> keybinding.
Use this keybinding in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+f",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
      "actions.find",
    ],
    "when": "explorerFocus"
  },
}
```

which will switch focus to your current editor and then open the Find Widget therein.

Comment: The first one worked for me! Thanks. My IDE nightmare is over. Chuckle.

Comment: I'm on a Mac so maybe it's different to Windows, but simply removing the cmd-F keybinding for `list.find` (using Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts) worked for me. Now pressing cmd-F always starts searching in the current editor pane, even if the explorer pane was focused - just like it used to be. No need for a macro.

Answer (score 9):

Three **SIMPLE** steps to achieve this without editing `keybindings.json`

**Step 1**: Open keyboard shortcuts  (`ctrl + k` `ctrl + s`)
**Step 2**: Type `list.find` inside the search bar.
**Step 3**: Change key-binding to f3. If there are multiple bindings  `f3` and `ctrl+f`, `remove` ctrl+f key-binding.

*You can also open keyboard shortcuts by:*
Opening the palette `ctrl + shift + p`, type open keyboard shortcuts.