# VS Code Each time when I select another file and start to type, I will type in the side bar, not on a page. How to fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I choose another file in it and press cmd + F to search, I start to search files in this side bar. But I want to search on the page! How to turn off searching in this side bar or turn off typing in this side bar. It's a big pain......

This side bar:

[image]

Comment: place the focus on the file with `Ctrl+1`, or double click in the file explorer to select file

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73739830/836330 - same question.