# Filtering a Treeview

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm new to TypeScript and the VS Code API. I'm looking to learn and am creating an extension that I've wanted a long time in order to do so. I managed to create the functionality I needed (basically a filename filter) using a WebView but I'd prefer using treeview. Here's what I've got:

Unfiltered file list

[image: unfiltered]

Filtered file list

[image: filtered]

Ideally, I'd like to create this:

[image: combo]

Is this currently possible and what keywords do I need to research to make it happen?

Thanks

Comment: [Document tree filtering](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_filtering-the-document-tree) seems to work with other TreeViews... would that work?

Comment: Mayyybe! Maybe I can use my own Search to send values to that filter! Thank you, I'll take a look.

Comment: Would [VSCode 1.70 (July 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73039128/6309) help?

Answer (score 1):

See the demo at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73039858/836330 of filtering in a TreeView.  It is not part of the extension-available api though.  You could trigger it in an extension with

```js
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('list.find');
```

but looking at the commit for this functionality I don't think there is any way to populate that find input from an extension - I don't think the command `list.find` takes any arguments.  I tried a couple of ways like

```js
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('list.find', {text: 'findMe'});
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('list.find', {query: 'findMe'});
```

Other find functionality in vscode can take arguments, but this filtering a treeView is brand new and will probably need a feature request if you want to populate the find input programmatically.