# VSCode find multiple files by name

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a big monorepo, and I'd like to list all `readme.md` files, so I can check if they need attention. So far I haven't found a way to do this.

- If I were to look for a single `readme.md`, I could use `Ctrl+P` which opens the file search menu, I see the list of `readme.md` files, but the list changes order, sometimes omits some items, it's meant to find a single file.
- If I knew a common piece of string, I could look for that in the search tab with `files to include` limited to `readme.md`, but this is not the case.

So is there a way to view a persistent list (like the search tab's results) for **all files with the same name?**

Comment: You can filter the Explorer in two different ways.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73039858/836330 for both.

Comment: @Mark that is awesome, if you want, add an answer, I'll accept it, otherwise I'll close this question as a duplicate in favour of the question you sent. TLDR.: click in the file tree and start typing :D

Comment: You can close it as a duplicate - thanks.