# Has the feature in vs code where you type to filter the document tree in file explorer been removed in latest versions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is this feature in vs code where when you start typing in the file explorer when focused, it shows a small filter box at the top and highlights similar matches on files in the explorer.

After updating to the latest version of Vs Code (Version 1.62.3, October 2021) this feature doesn't seem to work at all for me. Has it been removed or there is a problem with my computer (or version of Vs Code)?

Comment: @Mark I remember I had to switch it on, could it be `workbench.list.keyboardNavigation`

Comment: Yes @rioV8, you are close - it is `Workbench> List: Automatic Keyboard Navigation`.  But default is enabled  so odd that that functionality was lost.

Comment: @Mark In one of the release notes they mentioned this setting and you had to enable it, maybe now they have changed the default value because users expect it.

Comment: Is this what [VSCode 1.70 (July 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73039128/6309) will add?

Answer (score 3):

The focus type and old red box feature are deprecated. You can check

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73459511/7668448 for details.

In short. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_tree-find-control

`CMD + F` (mac) or `CTRL + F` (else) [while focused]

[image]

And for the default mode. `highlight` or `filter`. You can change that with:

```json
"workbench.list.defaultFindMode": "highlight"
"workbench.list.defaultFindMode": "filter"
```

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

By default it's `highlight`

## Work-around

<kbd>CTRL|CMD</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and search file using the `pallet`

- <kbd>Up/Down</kbd> for navigation
- <kbd>Right</kbd> to open the file without closing the pallet (quick check ...).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. [Search](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_filtering-the-document-tree) in explore field not working. In same time I have `"workbench.list.automaticKeyboardNavigation": true` in workspace and user property.
VSCode Version: 1.67.2 (Universal)

Comment: I found a reason my problem. I have vim add-on for vscode. In this situation you must focus on explore (mouse or `Command-Shift-E`), press`/` and then type something you want search. Vim way ))