# Hiding .js and .map files in VS Code while

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

What kind of settings can I use in Visual Studio Code to hide certain .js and .map files ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide .js.map files in Visual Studio Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587949/hide-js-map-files-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can configure the **files.exclude** properties in the **User Settings**.

Add this to your user settings file.

```js
{
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true,
    "**/*.js": true,
    "**/*.js.map": true
  }
}
```

You can open the settings file from the command pallet (ctrl + shift + p) and searching for settings.

Comment: I would still recommend you use tsconfig.json to output the js and sourcemaps to a separate folder, it makes it easier to maintain.

Comment: FYI to open the user settings follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-to-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file

Answer (score 18):

You probably don't want to blindly hide *all* `.js` and `.map` files, only the ones that are generated from an associated `.ts` file like you show in your screenshot.

To conditionally hide them, you're going to want to do this instead:

```
{
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true,
    "**/*.js.map": true,
    "**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does this go ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find `settings.json` in `.vs code` folder, you may generate it through vs code.

> File >> Preferences >> Settings >>

Notice the drop-down on the right side. 
Click on it and select the `workspace settings`.

You may paste your json settings.

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/*.js.map": true,
        "**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"},
        "**/node_modules/": true, <-- To hide node modules files
        "**/*.spec.ts": true <-- To hide cli generated files
    }
}
```

Make sure that you save the file.