# How can I hide autogenerated files by TypeScript in a NativeScript Project

Tags: nativescript

I'm new to NativeScript and TypeScript.  I'm building an app and finding all the extra .js and .js.map files in the app directory very distracting.

Is there a way to hide this files?

I'm playing around with the `"outDir": "./dist",` option in the `tsconfig.json` file.  It places all the generated files into the ./dist directory as expected.  When I run the project I get the following error:

`undefined: JS ERROR Error: Could not find module './'. Computed path '/LOCATION_OF_SIMULATOR/typescripttest.app/app'.`

I'm wondering if there is a way to have the runtime to check both the app directory and the dist directory?

Comment: I like the VSCode answer.  But I was wondering if there is a way to actually have the files in a different directory tree.  So any tool will not be cluttered with these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio code settings for hiding files.

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.css": true,
         "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"},
         "**/*.map": true       
    }    
}
```

[image: VS Code Settings]

Answer (score 2):

You can use VSCode to hide the files from the side bar by adding the following to your workspace or global vscode settings.json file.  Details at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32604188/690293).

```
{
   "files.exclude": {
       "**/.git": true,
       "**/.DS_Store": true,
       "**/*.js.map": true,
       "**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"}
   }
}
```