# .Net Core: Ignore folders by names

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core, csproj

For example I have a project with structure like this

[image]

How to ignore both 'node_modules' folders, but by pattern.

apps/[any_folder]/node_modules.

I have tried

```
remove="apps/**/node_modules/"
```

But looks like it doesn't works.

This is new .csproj file ( .net core ).

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803170/visual-studio-2017-csproj-core-file-exclusion?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa ?

Comment: Open the project in Visual Studio and right click the files and folders in Solution Explorer > Choose `Exclude from Project`