# Hide both ts and tsx generated JS files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

This question [has previously been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587949/hide-js-map-files-in-visual-studio-code) for hiding `.js` and `.js.map` files, when there is a `.ts` file with the same basename. The answer is that you set your VS Code settings to exclude `"**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"}`.

However, I'm wondering how I can hide the `.js` files when the basename is either `.ts` or `.tsx`. I need VS Code to check for either extension.

Essentially I need to have both `"**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"}` and `"**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).tsx"}`. Any ideas on how to get that done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with a *bit of a trick*, as [mentioned](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_hiding-derived-javascript-files) in VS Code documentation.

*To exclude JavaScript files generated from both .ts and .tsx source files, use this expression:*

`"**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts" },
    "**/**.js": { "when": "$(basename).tsx" }`

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1214) tracking a similar request, but no ETA at the moment.