# Open only specific folder in Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, visual-studio-code

I downloaded latest VScode from https://code.visualstudio.com/ on my Ubuntu 12.04.  The problem is when I do File / Open Folder and choose a specific folder it opens my entire /home/username in Explore section.  It even shows the hidden folders and files which is really annoying.

Has anyone seen this behavior and has suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140112/how-do-i-hide-certain-files-from-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code/30142299#30142299 ?

Comment: Thank you for providing a link to the other issue with useful info.  However, it's not what I was asking.  I don't want to hide specific files from sidebar.  I want to open ONLY a specific folder.

Comment: Ok this should work when you use File | Open Folder. Does it not?

Comment: That's the weird thing, it doesn't.  I launch VS Code, File, Open Folder, choose /home/dmitry/folder/subfolder and it opens /home/dmitry

Comment: And when you pass the folder to open from the command line?

Comment: Thank you. That worked.  I can't believe I did not think of it myself.  Still, rather odd behavior for File / Open Folder.

Comment: Sure, that sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Benjamin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851043/benjamin-pasero) suggestion here is a workaround:

```
./Code ~/folder_name/
```

Comment: VSCode adds an alias (quite sure it's by default) names ```code``` which opens the VSCode. ```code ~/folder/folder/``` will open that folder. (works on files too) (very much suggested)