# visual code - excluding files with several conditions

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is an option to exclude generated files with the "when" keyword, .e.g:

```
"files.exclude": {
  "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"},
}
```

I want to also exclude .js files that where generated from .tsx files. neither

```
"**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts, $(basename).tsx"}
```

nor

```
"**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"},
"**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).tsx"}
```

worked.

I also tried `"**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts*"}` and `"**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts | $(basename).tsx"}` in vain.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide certain files from the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140112/how-do-i-hide-certain-files-from-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: This Q&A is a **DUPLICATE OF:** _https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140112/how-do-i-hide-certain-files-from-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code_

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
"**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"},
"**/*?.js": { "when": "$(basename).tsx"}
```

Source: [Microsoft/vscode#1214](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1214)

Answer (score 2):

These are my settings if they help. It is quite a mess in creating these. I think that a regexp would be great, but we live in hard times ....

```
"files.exclude": {
"**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).tsx"},
"**/*?.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"},
"**/*.js.map": true
}
```