# .gitignore not ignoring node_modules/ folder

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

I am trying to get git to ignore my files in node_modules/ and it doesn't seem to be accepting this change.

Here is the content of my `.gitignore` file:

```
node_modules/
```

and here is my project structure:

[image]

I would expect the node_modules folder and all files/folders in it to be ignored by git, but instead I am getting a whole ton of changes listed as pending, and even when I do a git status in the root, node_modules/ is listed as pending. Is there some nomenclature about Windows that is making git act strangely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide certain files from the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140112/how-do-i-hide-certain-files-from-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of text in your question. Include the relevant code and configuration as *text*.

Answer (score 7):

Just add `/` before `node_modules/`, should be like

```
/node_modules/

# ^ forward slash before the folder name signifies root dir
```

If you are looking to exclude specific files only in node_modules folder, you can also do something like `/node_modules/*.json` will exclude all files inside root node_modules folder with `.json` extension.

Comment: This also did not work for me

Comment: As the question is on hold as "Questions seeking debugging help". It should work but its not working for you. Remove the .git folder and re init the git (if possible) Back up all first.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
node_modules/*
```

if you want to add the folder but not the content add a

```
.gitkeep
```

file to the folder and this to .gitignore

```
!node_modules/.gitkeep
```

Comment: I tried this and it still shows in git status.