# How do I show all files in the sidebar for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know how to hide files from the sidebar in Visual Studio Code:

- [How do I hide certain files from the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140112/how-do-i-hide-certain-files-from-)

However there are some files that I would like to have hidden the majority of the time but also display occasionally.

With Visual Studio I can facilitate this workflow with the Solution Explorer's "Show All Files" button:

[image]

How can I achieve a similar workflow in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in method to do this, but there are a couple of extensions out there like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.toggle-excluded-files