# How to exclude all but certain files in the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using Microsoft's Visual Studio Code, how do I show only certain files and file patterns in the sidebar and exclude all other files?

I want to show `.yml` files to achieve editing only them and not to scroll through all files.

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/*": true,
    "**/*.yml": false
}
```

P.S. I understand there is a way to hide certain files, but I want to show only specific files. I don't mind using an extension to achieve this.

Comment: Unfortunately this has been an open issue since 2015. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/869

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide certain files from the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140112/how-do-i-hide-certain-files-from-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get you pretty close:

```
"files.exclude": {

    "**/*.[^y]*": true,
    "**/*.y[^m]*": true,
    "**/*.ym[^l]*": true
}
```

It should exclude all files **except** those starting with a .ym(etc.) extension, like .yml, .ym, .ymabcdef, etc.  I don't know if you have any other files besides .yml that match that pattern.  I think right now this is as close as you can get to what you want.  The last entry doesn't seem to actually do anything though it should!!