# How to exclude all folders except one folder in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
└── target
    ├── W350
    ├── W400
    ├── W600
    ├── W600_HW_V2
    ├── W600_KT_HW_V2
    ├── W600_KT_HW_V2_neutral
    ├── W600_TK
    ├── W650
    ├── W650_HW_V2
    └── W750
```

I want to exclude all folders except `W600_KT_HW_V2`. VSCode should then show this tree:

```
└── target
    └── W600_KT_HW_V2
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33277809/9401556

Comment: Have you considered doing `cd 123` before running `code .`? Or just running `code 123`?

Comment: The above is just an example. The actual situation is much more complicated. I need to load the upper directory. I know use "**/abc", "**/def"， “**/fed” ...., too cumbersome

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, you could do this:

```
"files.exclude": {
  //  "**/node_modules": true,

  "**/[^1]*": true,    // all you need in your example
  "**/1[^2]*": true,
  "**/12[^3]*": true
},
```

In your case, only the first `"**/[^1]*": true,` would be  needed.  The additional lines would be used if you had folders like `1abc` that you also want excluded.  How deep you go depends on the similarity of your folder names.  But you don't give a lot of detail on how complicated your use case is.

But you see the pattern.   Vscode doesn't support `!` negation in `files.exclude` so you have to exclude everything but what you want with the `[^x]` form.

---

After you updated your file structure, it looks like this works:

```
"files.exclude": {
  "**/[^W]*": true,
  "**/W[^6]*": true,
  "**/W6[^0]*": true,

  "**/W600": true,         // the only one I had to "hardcode"
  "**/W600_[^K]*": true,
  "**/W600_KT_HW_V2_*": true
}
```

which isn't too bad considering how similar the only folder you want is to those to be excluded.  You can see the general pattern in the two examples - I was able to eliminate a few of the intermediates after similar folders were excluded earlier.

---

Also see [How to exclude all but certain files in the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331983/how-to-exclude-all-but-certain-files-in-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code/52333436#52333436) for doing this with file extensions.