# VS code: Useless file keep appearing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

## Visual Studio Code 1.46.1

Operating system: MacOS 10.15.4 (Catalina)
VS Code Package used: [C/C++](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools), [Code Runner](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner.git)

**Problem**: When I run a C++ code using Code Runner, a file with no extension [automatically appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApmWq.png).

I would like to know what does this 'useless file' do, and how to make these files stop from spawning.[image: file not displaying]

Comment: That is the executable. On unix and linux systems they typically have no extension. In other words, it's very far from useless.

Comment: Then, is it impossible to make VS code not generate this file or, at least, hide it?

Comment: Don't you want to generate an executable? Isn't it kinda the point of "run a C++ code using Code Runner"? Or do you just want to give it a different name?

Comment: build your C++ program to a location outside the project directory. CMake can help you with that

Answer (score 1):

That is the executable file also called binary file. They are the executable like .exe in windows so it is very useful(as it is the output of source code). If you dont want to see that file in sidebar of vscode then there is a good answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140112/how-do-i-hide-certain-files-from-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code). Alternatively you can configure your build configuration file (located at .vscode in you working directory) and set the build path to somewhere else

Comment: Okay. I found the option to hide certain filetypes, but my c++ executable file doesn't have an extension. How can I select files without an extension?

Comment: Here is my example configuration for task.json and launch.json. https://ibb.co/ypr5y2Y after having .out extension then you can hide that output

Comment: Okay, it seems like 2 solutions exist:
1. add an extension to executable and filter it
2. make a file for the executable (change build path)
I am new to this IDE and I have some trouble understanding your solution. Could somebody give me a step-by-step instructions? Thank you.

Comment: It is not solved, therefore I am leaving this question as incomplete.

Comment: what issue are u facing now?

Comment: I now know that these executable files are crucial, so I want to set up the location for my exe files. How can I?

Comment: What does 'bath' mean? Searched for it but cannot figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You are using Code Runner extension on vscode then you can modify the execution command.
Go to `Code-runner: Executor Map` Setting

I did this:

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    ...
    "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o ./temp/$fileNameWithoutExt && $dir./temp/$fileNameWithoutExt",
    ...
}
```

1. create a temp folder.
2. Now your temp folder will contain those unwanted files.
3. You can modify execution command like this for c++ also.