# How to hide autogenerated files from VS code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I want to hide auto generated dart files like `.g.dart`, `.freezed.dart` from vs code project. How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide certain files from the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140112/how-do-i-hide-certain-files-from-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Are the generated filenames somehow related to certain `.dart` filenames?

Comment: Yes, for example `file_name.freezed.dart`.

Comment: @Abion47 probably, but what should it be for a file name like : `file_name.freezed.dart`? Here I want to hide all the files having `freezed.dart`.

Comment: @Newaj Read the linked answer.

Answer (score 22):

create a folder

> .vscode

create

> settings.json

put this:

```
{
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/*.freezed.dart": true,
    "**/*.g.dart": true
  },
}
```

this make local configuration in your project.

Answer (score 18):

In v1.67 you can create an entry in the

`Explorer > File Nesting: Patterns` setting like so:

`*.dart`       `$(capture).g.dart, $(capture).freezed.dart`

[image: file nesting in dart demo]

`explorer.fileNesting.enabled`: Controls whether file nesting is enabled
`explorer.fileNesting.expand`: Controls whether file nests show as expanded by default
`explorer.fileNesting.patterns`: Controls how files get nested

---

In addition the `Explorer: Sort Order` setting has a new option:

> `foldersNestsFiles`:  Files and folders are sorted by their names.
> Folders are displayed before files. Files with nested children are
> displayed before other files.

`sortOrder.foldersNestsFiles`

See also [v1.67b Release Notes: File Nesting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_67.md#explorer-file-nesting)

Make sure you have  `Explorer > File Nesting: Enabled` true

Comment: While this solution only collapse them, rather than hiding them permanently as the questioner wanted, this is the solution I wanted. Those generated files will stop dirtying my explorer view, and at the same time, I can still check that they were really generated. This setting also allow us to collapse minified js and css file.

Answer (score 8):

### TL;DR

Type `Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + p`, choose `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` or `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)` and add:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/*.freezed.dart": true,
    "**/*.g.dart": true
},
```

You can add more patterns if you like. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options) you can find more information about the patterns.

### More info

You can configure this in your workspace or user settings:

Open settings: `Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + p` and search for 'Preferences: Open Settings'. You can choose from 'Workspace Settings' or your 'User Settings', depending on if you want to exclude the files just in your current project (workspace) or for all projects. And you can choose if you want to use the UI tool or to modify the settings json file manually.

#### Using the UI tool:

Search for `files.exclude` and you can add patterns you want to hide in the project explorer. In your case add `**/*.freezed.dart` and `**/*.g.dart`, but you can exclude [any pattern](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options) you like.

#### Editing the json file manually:

Type `Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + p` and search for 'Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)' or `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)`. Again, depending on if you want to exclude the files just in your current project (workspace) or for all projects.

Add this part to the json file:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/*.freezed.dart": true,
    "**/*.g.dart": true
},
```

Or add just the pattern lines, if `files.exclude` is already present in the settings.json file.

Answer (score 2):

"On Mac.
Open VSCode,
Type Shift+Command+P,
Preferences: Configure,
Language Specific Settings,
Choose the Language (Dart),
Then add to file "

> "files.exclude": {
> "**/.git": true,
> "**/.svn": true,
> "**/.hg": true,
> "**/CVS": true,
> "**/.DS_Store": true,
> "**/*.g.dart":true,
> }

#### Save

### Now, you don't see the *.g.dart files.