# VS Code explorer: Hide the generated .d.ts files only

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

In VS Code Explorer, I want to hide the files generated during TypeScript compilation.

When having a `my-file.ts`, generated files can be:

1. `my-file.js`
2. `my-file.js.map`
3. `my-file.d.ts`

Hiding the first two is easy, I need this in the `settings.json` of VS Code:

```json
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js.map": true,
        "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts" }
    }
}
```

But what about the third? I tried this one, but it hides ALL `.d.ts` files, even the standalone ones that are NOT generated from a `.ts` file.

```json
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.d.ts": { "when": "$(basename).ts", "__MY_PROBLEM": "It hides all .d.ts files" }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions to hide only those `.d.ts` files that are generated from a `.ts` file with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For another to "hide" generated files as of v1.64, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70748584/836330.

`Explorer > Experimental > File Nesting: Patterns` setting like so:

`*.ts`       `$(capture).js, $(capture).js.map, $(capture).d.ts`

---

I don't think it is possible to hide `*.d.ts` files associated with `*.ts` files.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/4642 where some people report that this works:

```
"**/*.map": {
    "when": "$(basename)"
}
```

to hide `*.js.map` files but I can't get

```
"**/*.ts": {
    "when": "$(basename)"
}
```

to do anything.  Maybe you will have better luck.

See also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/59368 unsuccessful.

And https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40850 talking about the fact that all `.d.ts` files are excluded.  Closed as "out of scope".  But you can upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off `.d.ts` emitting with `declaration:false` or [emit them
into a separate directory](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declarationDir):

```json
// tsconfig.json 
"compilerOptions": {
  "declaration": true,
  "declarationDir": "./types"  // configure the root directory for where declaration files are emitted
```

Comment: Thanks, these might be relevant for some but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Explorer Exclude plugin on vs code.  It takes care of the .d.ts files, .d.ts.map files, and whatever else you want to add.