# Exclude .history/ from the source control of vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

How can I exclude the .history folder from the source control of vscode?

[File history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOYOU.png)

I just want to commit the files themselves, not the changes in .history/.

Answer (score 2):

Add ".history/" to a .gitignore file on the project root.

Example:

```sh
echo .history/ >>.gitignore
```

It might be helpful to also add it to vscode's `files.exclude` setting.
From the plugin's [project page](https://github.com/zabel-xyz/local-history):

> Note
>
> When .history folder is stored in workspace, you can add a "files.exclude".
> This hides .history folder and avoids some issues. (e.g. csproj extension)
> Thanks to @pabloarista (issue [#13](https://github.com/zabel-xyz/local-history/issues/13))

For that, see: [How do I hide certain files from the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140112/how-do-i-hide-certain-files-from-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code/30142299#30142299)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file called `.gitignore` (if one does not exist already) and then add `.history/` to it, along with any other files or folders you would want git to ignore in commits.