# files not showing on vscode sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code, aws-amplify, ls

##### Overview

I have a folder with some directories and a couple of `.json` in it.
I know for certain, running `ls`, that there are 2 `.json` files... but vscode wont show one of them.

this must be some rule i cannot find because this pattern repeats for all my folders.

##### A bit of context:

i'm working with aws amplify, this happens in each function's folder (idk if also elsewhere) with the `function-parameters.json` file.

##### Something else

Also another file isn't showing: `amplify.state`

Comment: fund this: [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30142299/16656977)

Comment: Amplify must be adding this to the .vscode/settings.json when you initialize the project.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30142299/16656977) and then found that in my `preferences > files to exclude` i have that files, you guess, excluded.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+shift+E try this one.Ive search in google but i cant find the solution so i explored. And got this bro.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).