# VS Code "Find All References" Can't Ignore Excluded Files

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Highlighting a symbol, Right-Click --> Find All References (or Go To References) brings up a pane with all usages of that symbol in every file in my workspace. Unfortunately this includes `.ipynb_checkpoints/*` files and others making it hard to comb through results.

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30142299/5289570), I successfully removed `__pycache__` files by adding `**/__pycache__` to files:exclude in my User Settings. But adding `**/.ipynb_checkpoints/**` (and similar globs) there, nor to Files: Watcher Exclude did anything. Also tried this setting in my remote ssh settings and workspace settings.

Anyone know how to filter these references? FYI I'm running VS code 1.62.2 on Windows 10 and my configured remote SSH python executable is Python version 3.7 in a conda environment.

Comment: doesn't the glob need to be `**/.ipynb_checkpoints/**/*`? I thought globs couldn't end in a `**` or they did weird things or matched folders but I may be wrong.

Comment: I think you just need `**/dir_name`, which excludes any directory by that name in any part of the tree. I'm not sure what `**/dir_name/**` would do?

Ref => https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq?ref=hvper.com#_vs-code-gets-unresponsive-right-after-opening-a-folder

Answer (score 1):

Exclude from "Find All References" can be done via pylance setting.

```
{
        "python.analysis.exclude": [
        "**/build"
    ]
}
```