# How can I unload .NET/C#/F# projects in VS Code as in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio we can "unload" a project from the solution. This is useful because unloaded projects are not considered by the language services so there are not building errors, however they are still visible in the solution view.

How can we get the same result in Visual Studio Code (without removing the project from the solution)?

The project is written using .NET, F#, and C#, extensions OmniSharp and Ionide

EDIT

[An extensions exists](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spencer-farley.ionide-and-vscode-solution-explorer) that shows a Solution Explorer View in Visual Studio Code, with multiple "project oriented" features, lacking a "Unload/Exclude" function

[image]

Comment: "_An extensions exists_" - link to the marketplace page please.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code is not working with the concepts of projects (plural) but with folders ('open folder').

Hiding things (files or folders) can be done by configuration globally as well  as specific for your workspace. I found a good explanation of this feature here: [How do I hide certain files from the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140112/how-do-i-hide-certain-files-from-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code).

Comment: while this is true, I think there's a better answer to this question out there that'll have to do with configuring the extensions.